# Is there any android virtual device that has no phone service ?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I want to have a virtual android pad that has no phone service so that the following code of mine will work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" +  getPhoneNumber()));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) {
        //do alert
    }
```

However, I don't know which of the out-of-box virtual device has no calling service. I tried "10.1 WXGA (Tablet)", but it has calling service embedded.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a [unit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) and testing your code without be depending on that device?

[Google developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html) is a good place to start.